readr starts mid line
I am reading large files into R. Given their sizes, loading the entire file at once is not feasible, hence I am seeking to read and process the file line-by-line.
Initial attempts using base::readLines went smoothly, but due to special characters & error handling, it looks like I will need to use readr::read_lines instead. However, the two produce very different output on the second call.
Using base::readLines works as expected and matches the test file (though it is not suitable for some of the other parts of the problem).
con = file(file_path_and_name, "rb", encoding = encoding)

header_line = readLines(con, n = 1)
second_line = readLines(con, n = 1)

Using readr::read_line produces odd behavior. header_line is identical to the above method. But second_line is not the second line in the file but the end of line 490.
con = file(file_path_and_name, "rb", encoding = encoding)

header_line = readr::read_lines(con, n_max = 1)
second_line = readr::read_lines(con, n_max = 1)

I can get the second line of the file using the skip argument on a fresh file connection:
con = file(file_path_and_name, "rb", encoding = encoding)

second_line = readr::read_lines(con, n_max = 1, skip = 1)

As the problem only occurs on subsequent calls to readr::read_line, my hypothesis is that instead of reading a single line, readr is reading a chunk of the input file (and a chunk is ~490.5 lines of bytes). This means that when it resumes reading the same file, it does not resume from the next line.
What is going on here and how do I stop it?

You might be stuck with using readLines when reading from a connection https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/1444 . vroom::vroom and vroom::vroom_lines show the same behavior.

Have you tried using read_lines_raw?  Also, what is the problem you are running into with special characters and error handling?  There may be a better way to handle this with readLines.  And any chance you can provide access to the test file?

Did you look at readr::read_lines_chunked()?

Tested read_lines_raw and read_lines_chunked prior to asking the original question. Neither returned even a single row within an acceptable time frame. So these are not a feasible option.

Thank you for the issues link @AndreWildberg, my own searching failed to find these.

Sorry, can not share test file - it contains sensitive unit record data.
